# iOS: Parse issue in AudioComponent.h

Tags: xcode, ios6

I got "Parse issue" when using AVAudioPlayer in XCode 4.5.2, iOS6.
Anyone met this problems?

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting it now. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Not yet. I must back to xcode 4.2.